# Splitting Pandas dataframe into multiple mini-dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, split

This is the second part of a program im working on. I have a pandas dataframe that consists of:
[Title|df1_data1|df1_data2|df1_data3|df1_data4|df2_data1|df2_data2|df2_data3|df2_data4|df3_data1|df3_data2|df3_data3|df3_data4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiyMt.png)

**But theres two rules:**

1. The `df` will NOT always consist of 3 files (`df1`, `df2`, `df3`) there can be more or less.
2. There is ALWAYS 4 pieces of data per file.

I have the next step of the code written but the input needs multiple mini-dataframes of this bigger one.

So for this example of Three files I need to split the dataframe into

```
 1. |Title|df1_data1|df1_data2|df1_data3|df1_data4|
 2. |Title|df2_data1|df2_data2|df2_data3|df2_data4|
 3. |Title|df3_data1|df3_data2|df3_data3|df3_data4|
```

I'm currently trying to figure this out and i'm trying to loop through the headers and every four headers (not counting title) I create a dataframe... idk ima keep trying PLS HELP

Here's the big dataframe **REMEMBER THE RULES**

```
thisdict = {'Title': ['aaarrr','hahahamhm','yaaahooo','yaahoo', 'oopsymhm', 'ayorrr'],
        'df1_data1': ['324','123','444','NOTHING', 'NOTHING', 'NOTHING'],
        'df1_data2': ['4314','4321','7658','NOTHING', 'NOTHING', 'NOTHING'],
        'df1_data3': ['342','111','235','NOTHING', 'NOTHING', 'NOTHING'],
        'df1_data4': ['325','542','523','NOTHING', 'NOTHING', 'NOTHING'],
        'df2_data1': ['1','NOTHING','NOTHING','4', '3', 'NOTHING'],
        'df2_data2': ['2','NOTHING','NOTHING','3', '2', 'NOTHING'],
        'df2_data3': ['3','NOTHING','NOTHING','2', '4', 'NOTHING'],
        'df2_data4': ['4','NOTHING','NOTHING','1', '1', 'NOTHING'],
        'df3_data1': ['NOTHING','NOTHING','NOTHING','2', '67', '4'],
        'df3_data2': ['NOTHING','NOTHING','NOTHING','73', '2', '7'],
        'df3_data3': ['NOTHING','NOTHING','NOTHING','2', '4', '5'],
        'df3_data4': ['NOTHING', 'NOTHING', 'NOTHING', '1', '0', '9']
        }

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(thisdict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append `Title` as index (for just in case duplicate values of `Title`).  Then, create dict of split segments of columns according to length of total columns.

```
df2 = dataframe.set_index('Title', append=True)   # append for just in case duplicate values of Title

df_s = {(i+1): df2.iloc[:, i*4: i*4+4].reset_index(level=-1) for i in range(len(df2.columns) // 4)}
```

Then, you can access individual split dataframes by syntax of `df_s[i]`, e.g.

```
print(df_s[1])

       Title df1_data1 df1_data2 df1_data3 df1_data4
0     aaarrr       324      4314       342       325
1  hahahamhm       123      4321       111       542
2   yaaahooo       444      7658       235       523
3     yaahoo   NOTHING   NOTHING   NOTHING   NOTHING
4   oopsymhm   NOTHING   NOTHING   NOTHING   NOTHING
5     ayorrr   NOTHING   NOTHING   NOTHING   NOTHING


print(df_s[2])

       Title df2_data1 df2_data2 df2_data3 df2_data4
0     aaarrr         1         2         3         4
1  hahahamhm   NOTHING   NOTHING   NOTHING   NOTHING
2   yaaahooo   NOTHING   NOTHING   NOTHING   NOTHING
3     yaahoo         4         3         2         1
4   oopsymhm         3         2         4         1
5     ayorrr   NOTHING   NOTHING   NOTHING   NOTHING

print(df_s[3])

       Title df3_data1 df3_data2 df3_data3 df3_data4
0     aaarrr   NOTHING   NOTHING   NOTHING   NOTHING
1  hahahamhm   NOTHING   NOTHING   NOTHING   NOTHING
2   yaaahooo   NOTHING   NOTHING   NOTHING   NOTHING
3     yaahoo         2        73         2         1
4   oopsymhm        67         2         4         0
5     ayorrr         4         7         5         9
```

Comment: Quick question whats the '//' that you do in the For loop is that division?

Comment: @Mteyra  Yes, that is division that always yield an integer.  Since you can have variable number of 4 column segments (files), we can't hardcode the number of segments (files) and have to calculate it by the total number of columns (beside the `Title` column).

Comment: Oh I see I didn't know that was possible I always have to find a way around that lol,
and whats 'level' do in .reset_index?

Comment: @Mteyra  As I considered it deeply that your `Title` columns is possible to have duplicates, we cannot simply set `Title` as index (or else would give duplicate index).  As such we append the index.  This will make a 2 levels row index (1 is the original range index 0, 1, 2, ...5, the other is the `Title` column now as index).  Then, when we want to restore this 2nd level index `Title` back to data column from index, we need to specify in the `reset_index` command that we only want to reset this 2nd level index (-1 means the last level, i.e. 2nd here).

Comment: I didnt even think of duplicates ‍♂️
Thanks so so much mate hope to chat with you more in the future. 
I wish I could upvote for ya but dont got reputation lol

Comment: @Mteyra  If we don't specify the `level` parameter, we will reset ALL levels of row index and will get an extra new column named `index` with values of `0, 1, 2, ...5` as in the original row index.  This is not what we want.

Comment: @Mteyra  Haha, you just need 2 more reputations to upvote.  If you really appreciate, you can come back to upvote my answer when you get 2 more reputations later.   Anyway, happy programming!   :-)

Comment: I see, thanks so much. btw theres this thing in blue saying something about a chat whats that?

Comment: Im come back here 100% XD

Answer (score 0):

You can set Title as index and use filter to get the columns:

```
df = df.set_index('Title')
dfs = {'df%s' % i: df.filter(like='df%s' % i).reset_index()
       for i in range (1, 3+1)}
```

Comment: I've never been able to understand what the %'s do is there a simple explanation?